# What is the difference between Apache Spark SQLContext vs HiveContext?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

What are the differences between Apache Spark SQLContext and HiveContext ?

Some sources say that since the HiveContext is a superset of SQLContext developers should always use HiveContext which has more features than SQLContext. But the current APIs of each contexts are mostly same.

- What are the scenarios which SQLContext/HiveContext is more useful ?.
- Is HiveContext more useful only when working with Hive ?.
- Or does the SQLContext is all that needs in implementing a Big Data app using Apache Spark ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Spark 2.0+**

Spark 2.0 provides native window functions ([SPARK-8641](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8641)) and features some additional improvements in parsing and much better SQL 2003 compliance so it is significantly less dependent on Hive to achieve core funcionality and because of that `HiveContext` (`SparkSession` with Hive support) seems to be slightly less important.

**Spark < 2.0**

Obviously if you want to work with Hive you have to use `HiveContext`. Beyond that the biggest difference as for now (Spark 1.5) is a support for [window functions](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html) and ability to access Hive UDFs.

Generally speaking window functions are a pretty cool feature and can be used to solve quite complex problems in a concise way without going back and forth between RDDs and DataFrames. Performance is still far from optimal especially without `PARTITION BY` clause but it is really nothing Spark specific.

Regarding Hive UDFs it is not a serious issue now, but before Spark 1.5 many SQL functions have been expressed using Hive UDFs and required `HiveContext` to work.

`HiveContext` also provides more robust SQL parser. See for example: [py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError when selecting nested column in dataframe using select statetment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35015275/1560062)

Finally `HiveContext` is required to start Thrift server.

The biggest problem with `HiveContext` is that it comes with large dependencies.

Comment: From your comment, it seems HiveContext's only downside is it's large dependencies. Other than that, is it a safe bet to always use HiveContext instead of SqlContext. I am running SparkR 1.6 environment.

Comment: From https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-sql-SparkSession.html "SparkSession has merged SQLContext and HiveContext in one object in Spark 2.0."

Comment: In the engineering context, it is most important to consider that including "enableHiveSupport()" will use the hive JARs to start a local thrift server (typically on port 10000) that will communicate with the metastoreDB using the javax connection arguments in hive-site.xml.

Answer (score 5):

When programming against Spark SQL we have two entry points depending on
whether we need Hive support. The recommended entry point is the HiveContext to
provide access to HiveQL and other Hive-dependent functionality. The more basic
SQLContext provides a subset of the Spark SQL support that does not depend on
Hive.

-The separation exists for users who might have conflicts with including all of
the Hive dependencies.

-Additional features of HiveContext which are not found in in SQLContext include the ability to write queries using the more complete HiveQL parser, access to Hive UDFs, and the ability to read data from Hive tables.

-Using a HiveContext does not require an existing Hive setup.

Comment: for further reading refer https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/sql-programming-guide.html

Comment: even sql context does not require hive setup

Answer (score 3):

HiveContext is still the superset of sqlcontext,it contains certain extra properties such as it can read the configuration from hive-site.xml,in case you have hive use otherwise simply use sqlcontext

Comment: Can I set hive properties such as hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true using swlContext ?