# How to concurrently use two DataFrames in different notebooks?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using `Apache spark` and `SqlContext` in a notebook in `Jupyter`, in order to read and process data from a `DataFrame`. Besides, at the same time I want to have another Notebook that involves the creation and manipulation of another `DataFrame`.

Additionally, I followed the step list detailed in this post: [Link Spark with iPython Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33064031/link-spark-with-ipython-notebook/33065359#33065359). Because I want to run `Apache spark` using notebooks.

However, when I try to run two notebooks at the same time, I get the following error:

> Exception: ("You must build Spark with Hive. Export 'SPARK_HIVE=true'
>   and run build/sbt assembly", Py4JJavaError('An error occurred while
>   calling None.org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.\n', JavaObject
>   id=o27))

My spark configuration is very simple, it just run locally, for more details just see the following link: [Spark's configuration](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0daa9448f312b41856cc)

Therefore, my question is how I can run two Notebooks concurrently in `Apache Spark` and in `Jupyter`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't depend on the [features provided by `HiveContext`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33666545/1560062) you can use plain `SQLContext` instead (`from pyspark import SQLContext; sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)`.

Comment: What about if I try to create two `RDD`s in two different notebooks? Will this also work even if I read them from a CSV for example?