# Understanding how Hive SQL gets executed in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, mapreduce, pyspark

I am new to spark and hive. I need to understand what happens behind when a hive table is queried in Spark. I am using PySpark

Ex:

```
warehouse_location = '\user\hive\warehouse'
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark =SparkSession.builder.appName("Pyspark").config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouse_location).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

DF = spark.sql("select * from hive_table")
```

In the above case, does the actual SQL run in spark framework or does it run in MapReduce framework of Hive.

I am just wondering how the SQL is being processed. Whether in Hive or in Spark?

Comment: When a hive query is applied to a dataframe, it converts to SparkSQL before processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SparkSQL` allows reading and writing data to `Hive` tables. In addition to `Hive` data, any `RDD` can be converted to a `DataFrame`, and `SparkSQL` can be used to run queries on the `DataFrame`.

The actual execution will happen on `Spark`. You can check this in your example by running a `DF.count()` and track the job via `Spark UI` at `http://localhost:4040`.

Comment: Thanks. Are u saying that though it uses the Hive table, the query execution(select * from ) happens at Spark. Meaning spark will directly read the underlying table files from file system?

Comment: Yes, correct. `SparkSQL` will leverage the `Hive` metastore to access metadata for the `Hive` tables. Then, the work of reading the table files from disk, and processing them and running the query is all done via the `Spark` engine.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it. In general does SparkSQL mean executing SQL queries like in the above example in Spark?

Comment: `SparkSQL` allows executing `SQL` queries on existing `Hive` tables via `spark.sql("query")`. This is great since you can improve performance, while using the `Hive` setup in existing `Hadoop` cluster. `SparkSQL` can also be used via the `DataSet API`. Here, you construct a `Dataset/DataFrame` from existing `RDD`/data file (e.g. `JSON`, `Parquet`), and then use transformations like `filter()`, `groupBy()`, `map()` on it. A `DataFrame` provides tabular view of data,  and since it has a schema associated with it, `SparkSQL` can process it more efficiently than a plain `RDD`.

Answer (score 4):

`enableHiveSupport()` and `HiveContext` are quite misleading, as they suggest some deeper relationship with Hive.

In practice Hive support means that Spark will use Hive metastore to read and write metadata. Before 2.0 there where [some additional benefits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33666545/9613318) (window function support, better parser), but this no longer the case today.

Hive support **does not** imply:

- Full Hive Query Language compatibility.
- Any form of computation on Hive.

Comment: Thanks but my question was how the SQL query is being processed. It is in Spark or Hive(MapReduce) framework?

Comment: Does query execution(select * from ) happen at Spark? Will spark directly read the underlying table files from file system?

Comment: Data is processed by Spark. There is no Hive  / MapReduce involved.